# ckfinder's browse for images not working properly on ckeditor php

Tags: php, html, ckeditor, image-upload, ckfinder

I am working on a core php. There is a page for products to add or edit their title description, images etc.

For product description I used `ckeditor` plugin its working perfectly but there is no option for image uploading, so I add one more plugin `ckfinder` for upload the images. When I click on browse for image upload it open a blank window and shows me this message

> The file browser is disabled for security reasons. Please contact your system administrator and check the CKFinder configuration file.

I don't know what this means and how can I configure this.

Here is my HTML Code index.html:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<textarea name="testEditor" id="testEditor"></textarea>
<script>
    // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
    // instance, using default configuration.
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'testEditor',
                        {
                            filebrowserBrowseUrl : 'http://localhost/editor/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
                            filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : 'http://localhost/editor/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
                            filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl : 'http://localhost/editor/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash',
                            filebrowserUploadUrl : 'http://localhost/editor/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
                            filebrowserImageUploadUrl : 'http://localhost/editor/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
                            filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : 'http://localhost/editor/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash',
                            filebrowserWindowWidth : '1000',
                            filebrowserWindowHeight : '700'
                        }
                    );
</script>
```

Please help me, I am working on ckeditor and ckfinder for first time.

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/file-browser-disabled-for-security-reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `config.php` file in CKFinder root.

By default, CKFinder will not work due to authentication restrictions. You must first make sure that you have configured it correctly, and then enable it. This is to make sure that no unauthorized user can upload and access files on your server.

Once you have completely configured CKFinder, you are ready to enable it for use. The `CheckAuthentication()` function is used for that. In this function you must implement the code ensuring that the requests are coming from an authenticated user. This is usually done by assigning a session variable when the user logs into your system.

You can read more [in the documentation here](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/PHP/Configuration/Quick_Start#The_CheckAuthentication.28.29_Function).

Do note that unlike CKEditor, CKFinder is not an Open Source product and you [need a license](http://cksource.com/ckfinder) to use it for purposes other than evaluation.

Comment: I use textarea in many pages and give same id ... can this make some issue or not

Comment: Element `id` [must be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id), as per HTML specifications.